# How to configure network interfaces on Ubuntu and CentOS with Ansible variables?

Tags: networking, ansible

I am searching for an OS-independent version of https://github.com/linux-system-roles/network:

- It should work for Debian>=10, Ubuntu>=18.04 and CentOS>=8
- It should support interface bonding
- The network interfaces should be configurable with host variables, similar to this:

```yaml
- name: NIC Configuration 
  hosts: webservers
  vars:
    network_connections: 
      - name: ens4
        type: ethernet
        ip:
          address:
            - 172.25.250.30/24
  roles:
    - rhel-system-roles.network
```

Are there any roles like this?

I do know the [community.general.nmcli](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html) module, however, the example there looks quite complicated: ansible-nmcli does not allow to configure the network via variables, instead one has to set the role parameters by hand.